# How can I get a server's public key from the NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlconnection

My app connects to a server using TLS, and receives a token from the server. It needs to verify the authenticity of the token by checking its signature against the server's public key, retrieved from the `SecTrustRef` object I can get in `-connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` like so

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
  if /* server trust authentication method and server is trusted */ {
    SecTrustRef trust = [challenge.protectionSpace serverTrust];
    self.serverPublicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust);
  }
}
```

But if I disconnect from the server and then connect to it again my delegate's `-connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` method is not called and I don't have a chance to store the server's public key. It appears that the system is caching the server's credentials and the client credentials that I send to the server.

Is there a way to retrieve these cached credentials so I can get the server's public key in `-connectionDidFinishLoading:` or some other delegate callback that only gives me the `NSURLConnection`?